# Pre filled data to Microsoft Service booking page

Tags: outlook, calendar, microsoft-graph-booking

This is my  Microsoft Service booking page of one Service

```
https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/XXXXXX/bookings/s/XXXXXX
```

I have added one field CaseID, and I want to prefill the CaseID field with any value Bind to URL like? CaseID=1345

or by any other method, when the link opens

What are the possible options available?

I am not able to find anything on Microsoft

I found one related post to set a market campaign ID like this

https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/TailspinToys@contosopetscom.onmicrosoft.com/bookings/?RefID=Twitter

But it not working on my Services

[image]